# How to create an .app which is a wrapper around a python application?

Tags: python, macos, automator, xen

I recently was forced by my company to migrate over to a Mac PC and I am finding that I need to find linux applications to replace certain applications that are only available on Windows.  One example is the management console for XenServer hypervisor.  I found that there is an open source project called [openXenManager](https://github.com/OpenXenManager/openxenmanager).  I found it quite easy to build and install.  But after installing the application I found that there was no launcher.  So, I can either run it manually by going to a terminal and typing:

```
/usr/local/bin/openxenmanager
```

Or I have learned that I can use Mac's Automator to create a launcher or what Mac calls an ".App". So, I decided to create an ".App" with Automator.

[image]

I saved the newly created OpenXenManger.app to the applications folder and then decided to change the icon. From:

[image]

To:

[image]

I did that by doing the following:

1. Open up finder then going to applications
2. Right click on the .app
3. Select get info
4. Open the image that I wanted to use in an editor
5. Command + a
6. Command + c
7. Then go to the Info window
8. Click on the small icon on the left top
9. Then paste Then close the get info window

The problem that I am now having is that after launching the application, the application opens as a new icon in the dock.  As you can see in the image below they are side by side:

[image]

How can I get the app to use only the OpenXenManager.app and not display the python rocket?

If you are interested in the file that script that launches the OpenXenManager (/usr/local/bin/openxenmanager):

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'openxenmanager==0.1b1','openxenmanager'
__requires__ = 'openxenmanager==0.1b1'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('openxenmanager==0.1b1', 'openxenmanager')
```

Comment: I suspect this happens no matter whether you run `/usr/local/bin/openxenmanager` yourself, or through automator. Correct? In that case, automator isn't really relevant in this question

Comment: If I run it from the command line the rocket icon does pop up in the launcher.  How do people create a .app which is a wrapper around a python application?

Comment: I suggesgt you update your question to reflect this. The Automator part is a red herring

Comment: Ok, I just changed the question.